# Show loading gif onkeypress

Tags: javascript, gif, onkeypress

So I have an input and dataList:

```
<div id="namearea">
        <h2>City Name:</h2>

        <div>
            <input id="citiesinput" list="cities">
            <datalist id="cities"></datalist>

            <button id="search">
                Search
            </button>

            <span class="loading" id="loadingnames">
                <img src="/gif" alt="icon" />
                Loading...
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have already used JS to fill the dataList with options.

What I want to do is display the loading gif from when i start typing in the input until I have chosen an option or pressed the search button

current JS:

```
var cityArray;

window.onload = function() {
    processCities();

    document.getElementById("search").onclick = findWeather;
    document.getElementById("citiesinput").addEventListener("onkeypress", showLoad);


};

function showLoad () {
    var input = document.getElementById("citiesinput").value;
    if(input !== "" || cityArray.indexOf(input) == -1) {
        document.getElementById("loadingnames").style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have put a fiddle together for you [here](https://jsfiddle.net/r5oxjdwy/). I use the `keyup` event because the `keypress` event is called before the first key is registered in the input value.

```
input.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    loading.style.display = input.value.length ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

You must also remember to remove the loader if the condition is not met.

Answer (score 0):

Use opacity instead of display. Reason being when you set the display to inline-block, you will find your parent div "glitching" its height to adjust its content to the image div

Use keyup event after you press a key, it will trigger the function

```js
var cityArray;
cityArray = ["city1", "city2"]

function findWeather() {

}
window.onload = function() {
  //processCities();

  //document.getElementById("search").onclick = findWeather;
  document.getElementById("citiesinput").addEventListener("keyup", showLoad);
  document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("click", showLoad);


};

function showLoad() {
  var input = document.getElementById("citiesinput").value.trim();
  if (input == "") {
    document.getElementById("loadingnames").style.opacity = "0";
    return
  }
  if (cityArray.indexOf(input) == -1) {
    document.getElementById("loadingnames").style.opacity = "1";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("loadingnames").style.opacity = "0";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="namearea">
  <h2>City Name:</h2>

  <div>
    <input id="citiesinput" list="cities">
    <datalist id="cities"></datalist>

    <button id="search">
      Search
    </button>

    <span class="loading" id="loadingnames" style="opacity:0;">
    <img src="http://bestwallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/animated-wallpaper-gif.gif" alt="icon " id="city_img " style="width:50px;height:50px;"/>Loading...
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```